# mapping ids to multiple async functions and waiting for all to complete

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a list of IDs and I am trying to query two different servers for each ID in the list.

I wrote two async functions `task1` and `task2`. These return a value from the server for a given ID.

I was able to figure out this `Promise.all` structure below which can do the map. But I would like all of these promises to fully-complete before I move on to the next step. How can I do this?

I was about to resort to something like: `while page2.task1 == null: wait 5 seconds` but I figured I would ask here first, could someone please help me understand the correct way to do this?

```
class Page {
    task1 = null;
    task2 = null;
    input_id_obj = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    constructor() {}
}
let page = new Page();

async function task1(id){fetch...}
async function task2(id){fetch...}

Promise.all(
    page.input_id_obj.map((val, key)=> async_task1(val.id))
).then((values) => {
    page.task1 = values;
});

Promise.all(
    page.input_id_obj.map((val, key)=> async_task2(val.id))
).then((values) => {
    page.task2 = values;
});
```

I tried this but the console.log still prints NULL.

```
async function asyncTask1(){
    Promise.all(
        page.input_id_obj.map((val, key)=> async_task1(val.id))
    ).then((values) => {
        page.task1 = values;
    });
}
async function asyncTask2(){
    Promise.all(
        page.input_id_obj.map((val, key)=> async_task2(val.id))
    ).then((values) => {
        page.task2 = values;
    });
}

async function asyncPromAll() {
    const resultArray = await Promise.all([asyncTask1(), asyncTask2()]);
    console.log("page.task1=", page.task1);
    console.log("page.task2=", page.task2);
}
asyncPromAll()
```

Comment: Instead of Promise.all you may need to use Promise.allSettled https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have two async functions task1 and task2.
You almost reached a goal by yourself.

```
async function task1(){...}
async function task2(){...}
```

Now we just need to create an array of this tasks and wait till they all finish

```
let arr = [task(),task2()];
// results in this case will contain the answers of both of your requests
let results = await Promise.all(arr);
```

Comment: I'm doing this in a fetch though. Fetch data from some server .then do some tasks. So I get an error await is only valid in async functions

Comment: I edited question also tried your solution still getting issues

Comment: @Frank since `asyncPromAll` was declared as `async` they return a `Promise` that should be handled either with `await` or with 'chaining' functions like `then()`